# JQTouch Pressure Sensitivity

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch

I noticed an interesting bug with the JQTouch platform and wanted to know if anyone else has run into it our has a workaround for it. If I have a link with an `onclick` event and lightly tap the link on the iPhone, the link works, but the click event is not fired. If I tap the same link harder, the event fires.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try handling the `tap` event provided by jQTouch, rather than the `click` event.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed the same issue. My solution is to use for the iPhone tap events and for other devices click events (see http://digitalize.ca/2010/02/jqtouch-tap-vs-click/). I am wondering though if there is a better solution.